# Youtube sometimes doesn't play the Video

Tags: javascript, html, css, layout

i have seen many post on SO there I got recommended to use mute. The problem is that from a list of embed urls, sometimes a video is not playing. I am hiding the iFrame and I think its because ads. So i came here to ask you guys, maybe you can help me to solve the problem.

HTML:

```
<iframe
        src=""
        width="500"
        height="500"
        frameborder="0"
        class="youtube-player hidden"
        allow="autoplay"
></iframe>
```

This function would be triggered every 15 sek

```
function changeElementOnWebpage() {
    let soundtrackKey = ""
    shows.forEach((showObj, index) => {
        soundtrackKey = showObj.soundtrack
    })
    let ytURL = getSolidEmbedYTUrl(soundtrackKey)
    document.querySelector(".youtube-player").src = ytURL
}
```

Generated URL by JS:

```
function getSolidEmbedYTUrl(soundtrackKey) {
   return `https://www.youtube.com/embed/${soundtrackKey};autoplay=1&mute=0`
}
//https://www.youtube.com/embed/PtJ6yAGjsIs?start=0;end=15;autoplay=1&mute=0
```

My Datas where I pick the video.

```
const shows = [
{
    soundtrack: "s7L2PVdrb_8?start=0;end=15",
},
{
    soundtrack: "RcPZdihrp4?start=0;end=15",
},
{
    soundtrack: "of-Bqmlgj98?start=0;end=15",
},
{
    soundtrack: "8ZzVZs3C3kU?start=10;end=25",
},
{
    soundtrack: "fBITGyJynfA?start=0;end=15",
},
```

If you need more information, please Ask.

Best Regards
Linda

Answer (score 0):

Can I see your javescript code to? sorry that I ask this in a anwser but I don't have enough points to comment or something.